# WPF background operations using Asynchronous Workflows

Tags: asynchronous, f#

To execute operations on a background thread and avoid blocking the UI in a WPF application, I often find myself writing this pattern:

```
async {
    // some code on the UI thread

    let uiThread = SynchronizationContext.Current
    do! Async.SwitchToThreadPool()

    let! result = // some Async<'t>

    do! Async.SwitchToContext uiThread

    // do things with the result if it wasn't () all along
}
```

1. Am I doing this right at all? Is this idiomatic? Should it be done differently?
2. If this is correct, of course I would prefer not to have to do it like that all the time - is there a built-in shorter way to achieve the same thing? None of the existing `Async` functions appears to do something like that.
3. If not, does it make sense to just turn the above code into a function?

   ```
   let onThreadPool operation =
       async {
           let context = SynchronizationContext.Current
           do! Async.SwitchToThreadPool()

           let! result = operation

           do! Async.SwitchToContext context

           return result
       }
   ```

That adds another level of `async { }` nesting - can this cause issues at "some" point?

Comment: you should not have issues no - but the `uiThread = SynchronizationContext.Current` inside the workflow might be a problem - I would make sure to put it outside the `async` or write an extension-method for WPFs dispatcher (that is what I usually do) to deal with async computations.

Comment: What potential problem do you see with capturing the original context inside the workflow? What is the difference to doing it outside? And what would the extension method do/look like?

Comment: basically what Tomas hinted at: if you go `Start` or use the workflow inside another you could end up on something different than the UI thread (you capture it in the context where the workflow finally runs) - so I would capture the context where you call/define your workflow instead - it just seems more natural to me

Comment: I am aware of that; that's actually why I explicitly called the value `context` in the `onThreadPool` function (as opposed to `uiThread` above). When I call this, I should always be aware what context I'm coming from, and I can be sure that when it returns I am exactly in the same place again after the operation I passed into it ran on the ThreadPool.

Comment: BTW - Just because I saw this, even though it's very old - it's far safer to pass a control, and build a DispatcherSynchronizationContext from the UI itself. You can use this constructor https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchersynchronizationcontext.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Threading_DispatcherSynchronizationContext__ctor_System_Windows_Threading_Dispatcher_ to build the context on the fly instead of grabbing "current", which allows your routine to be usable from anywhere, as well as allowing the async to be passed through other async functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing here definitely makes sense. One useful operation here is [`Async.StartImmediate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee620671.aspx), which starts the async workflow on the current thread. If you call this from the UI thread, this guarantees that the workflow will also start on the UI thread and so you can capture the synchronization context inside the workflow.

The other trick is that many built-in asynchronous F# operations automatically jump back to the original synchronization context (those that are created using `Async.FromContinuations`, including e.g. `AsyncDownloadString`), so when you're calling one of those, you do not even need to explicitly jump back to the original synchronization context.

But for other asynchronous operations (and for non-async operations that you want to run in the background), your `onThreadPool` function looks like a great way of doing this.

Comment: Thanks; I'm glad you approve, because I'm sure I learned the overall way to do this from your blog. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

@random-dev is right capturing the context must happen outside the workflow

```
let onThreadPool operation =
    let context = SynchronizationContext.Current
    async {
        do! Async.SwitchToThreadPool()

        let! result = operation

        do! Async.SwitchToContext context

        return result
    }
```